# Mitm Attack on WebRtc

Tags: javascript, webrtc

i have a problem. I've developed a web-app using WebRtc for one-to-one videocall via browser using WebRtc with signalling server on node js (listening e.g. on 8181 port).

Now i would implement MITM attack. I was thinking that, wheen Peer_1 should invoke two rtc peer connection, one for the second peer (Peer_2), one to the MITM. The same thing for the second peer.

Now, i was thinking that signalling server needs to listen on another port, for each rtc peer connection received from the two peers (e.g. 8282 for Peer_1 and 8383 for Peer_2).

Am i right? I think that because signalling server's implementation is to one-to-one communication.

In this way, signalling server on port 8181 allows end-to-end communication for Peer_1 and Peer_2, on 8282 there is the signalling path for Peer_1 and the MITM, and on 8383 for MITM and Peer_2.

Am i right or not? Thanks for the support.

Answer (score 2):

*Man in the middle* refers to interception during transmission, which WebRTC itself is secured against using DTLS and key exchange, so the weak point is usually the signaling server chosen by an application instead.

But what you describe however sounds like *Man on both ends*. You have to trust the service (the server) to guarantee whom you're being connected to. If that server is compromised, or either client is compromised - say by injection - then there's no guarantee whom you're talking to, since a client can easily forward a transmission to another party.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. So you think that my solution is appropriate? I was thinking in this way because WebRtc uses DTLS+Certificate Digest in SDP. Is that the right solution?

Comment: @pier92 I have no interest in actually helping attack a WebRTC connection.