# How to protect WebRTC from MitM attack?

Tags: static, webrtc, assets

I am working on a PoC with WebRTC for static assets, and discovered it could be hacked with a MitM : https://webrtchacks.com/webrtc-and-man-in-the-middle-attacks/. Is there a way to prevent WebRTC from such an attack ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Mitm Attack on WebRtc](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39189441/mitm-attack-on-webrtc)

Answer (score 1):

Note that the post starts by compromising the signaling server. You can safely assume that if the signaling server is compromised everything goes down the drain. The reason for that, is that at the end of the day you need to trust some kind of an entity to broker the communication and that's the signaling server.

Only thing you need to do to protect against such an attack is to protect your signaling server - something quite common in the web today.