# Should WebRTC's SDP be private for secure communication?

Tags: security, webrtc, sdp

There are `ice-ufrag` and `ice-pwd` parameters in SDP, but do they (or any other parameters) really need be private for secure end-to-end connection if I can ensure SDP offer/answer was not modified (with digital signature as an example)?

The use case is P2P system where I have a public key of the other side and want to ensure I'm actually securely connected to it. The other side however doesn't have my public key and doesn't care who am I.

WebRTC and related specs are too large so that I didn't find clear answer to this question yet (HTTPS is recommended everywhere, but not much besides that), also I haven't found any article that considers WebRTC security from this point of view. Hopefully someone with deep WebRTC knowledge can clarify this question.

Questions that this one was marked as possible duplicates of do not include any proof of the SDP origin (in form of digital signature or in some other way), which is why this question is in unique.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Mitm Attack on WebRtc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39189441/mitm-attack-on-webrtc)

Answer (score 2):

**Absolutely!** While WebRTC secures its data communication, the SDP is a free ticket to call you.

If you don't secure your signaling channel then you may end up having a perfectly secure call with an attacker, who unbeknownst to you forwards packets to and from your intended call recipient.

This is a variant of [Man-in-the-middle attack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man-in-the-middle_attack). See [security.stackexchange.com](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/56775/is-webrtc-safe-against-man-in-the-middle-attacks) for more.

Comment: Linked issue is not what I'm asking here. It doesn't include digital signature for SDP or any other proof of its origin.
With Diffie–Hellman key exchange you can in fact establish secure communication over insecure channel, you just need to make sure to connect to intended recipient, so I'm curious whether it is similar for WebRTC or not.

Comment: @nazar-pc Ah ok. But how can you ensure the SDP answer was not modified if the other side doesn't have your public key?

Comment: The other side (in my use case) doesn't care about me, I'm basically anonymous to it, so there is no need to check SDP authenticity on the other side.